# SSIS Export to CSV - Setting a Single Column to TEXT

Tags: ssis

This one is doing my head in, hopefully there is a really simple answer.

I am exporting data out of a SQL database into a CSV file. One of the fields in the database is a unique client reference, mine would be SLJX01, as an example.

When I check the export in Excel, there are a number of references that now appear as dates, so for example MARC02 appears as Mar-02, APRI05 is Apr-05.

How can I stop this from happening, as the references are key to the data migration process that the files are used for? I have tried setting the Text Qualifier on my Connection Manager but that didnt do anything, same result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answered it myself. DONT OPEN THE CSV IN EXCEL!!! If I open it in Notepad, the references are OK. Doh!